# I need help for a very simple function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, arduino, simulink

In the picture, a part of my Simulink model is shown.

[image: Part of the simulink model]

It works like this:

- `Data` is what is sent from *serialport*. When I start the
  simulation, if there is data sent, `Data` has the value of it. When
  there is not any data sent, `Data` sends 0 as output.
- `Status` is 1 when there is data on *serialport* and 0 when there is
  not any data sent.
- What I want it to do is: "If there is any data in *serialport*, give
  `y` the value of sent data. If there is no data sent keep, `y` as the
  previous value".

So I added my own User Defined Function

```
function y = fcn(u,x)
   if (x == 0)
      y = y;
   else
      y = u;
   end 
end
```

But this gives me the error says `y` is not defined.
How can I achieve this simple solution wiht or without any user defined function? Can somebody, please, figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think you need to pass `y` too into the function - `function y = fcn(u,x,y)`

Comment: I haven't think of that. Thank you very much, I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing this function, I would use an enabled subsystem with the default settings from the library (no block in it). When enable is zero, the output is held.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The "not equal is actually  "~=", as stated in another comment.

It seems to me that you're missing brackets from your function definition:

```
function [y] = fcn(u,x)
if (x == 0)
    y = y;
else
    y = u;
end 
end
```

Its fine tuning, but I think that could be done a little more beautifully.
Here is my untested version:

```
function [y] = fcn(u,x)
//% "!=" means "not equal"
//% So when x isn't 0 the amount of u is added to y
if (x != 0)
    y = u;
end 
end
```

Comment: In matlab not equal is "~=". And I will try brackets and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Brackets are not required when there is only one output.  (The problem is as described in other answers.)